# JUnit How to Test methods that create New Objects

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I want to test the `consumeEvents` in the following class using Junit5 in Spring Boot

```java
    public class Consumer {
    
        private final ConsumerInterface interface;
    
        public void consumeEvents(Event event) {
                EventA eventA = new EventA();
                eventA.setPayload(event.getPayload());
                interface.handleEvent(eventA.extractModel());
            } 
        }
    }
```

the `extractModel()` returns an **EventPayload** class

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    class ConsumerTest {

    @Mock
    ConsumerInterface consumerInterface;

 
    private Consumer consumer;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(){
        consumer = new Consumer(consumerInterface);
    }
    @Test
    public void consumeEvents() {
        var event = Mockito.mock(Event.class);
        var eventPayload = Mockito.mock(EventPayload.class);

        /* --------- not working as a solution ------  */
        EventA eventA = Mockito.spy(new EventA());
        when(eventA.extractModel()).thenReturn(eventPayload);
        /* ------------------------------------------  */

        doNothing().when(paymentRequester).handleReceiptPaymentReceivedEvent(any());

        consumer.consumeEvents(event);

        verify(consumerInterface, times(1)).handleEvent(eventPayload);
    }

}
```

The test fails,

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at EventA.extractModel

How to mock the new created instance inside the method (EventA)  ?

Comment: Why would you need to mock it? Make the mocked `event.getPayload()` return something so that `EventA` properly initializes and can return properly from `extractModel`. Which you could verify with an argument captor.

Comment: I want to verify that the method `handleEvent` was invoked with the right argument, otherwise we should use `any()`

Comment: You should test `EventA` and that it returns the proper thing separately, you are now combining 2 things. If you really want to check the argument you can always use an `ArgumentCaptor` and validate the actual argument.